# Change class name only for one div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to change "+" on "-" by changing the class name and using "ng-click" event, but it changes all "+" elements on "-" in all divs.

[image]

[image]

Any Idea how to change it only in that div that I clicked?

Here is my code

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="margin-display" >
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" >
            <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="band in bands">
                <div ng-class="$even ? 'odd' : 'even'">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <!-- calling ng-click event  with  changeClass() function-->
                        <div ng-click="changeClass()" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" ng-href="#collapse{{band.index}}" > 
                            <img ng-src="{{band.image}}" alt=""> 
                            <p class="output">{{band.artist}}</p>
                            <p class="output">{{band.track}}</p>  
                            <p class="output">{{band.collection}}</p>  
                            <p class="output">{{band.genre}}</p>    
                            <span ng-class="class"></span> <!-- class name change--> 
                        </div>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div ng-attr-id="collapse{{band.index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body" ng-class="$even ? 'odd' : 'even'" >
                        <div>   
                            <h3>{{band.artist}} - {{band.track}}</h3>
                            <p><strong>Collection: </strong> {{band.collection}}</p>  
                            <p><strong>Track Count: </strong>{{band.trackAmount}}</p>  
                            <p><strong>Price: </strong>{{band.collPrice}} USD</p>  
                            <p><strong>Duration: </strong>{{band.trackDuration | date:'mm:ss'}} min</p> 
                            <p><strong>Track Price:</strong>{{band.collPrice}} USD</p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

JS

```
//class name change function
    $scope.class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus" //name of class;
    $scope.changeClass = function(){
        if ($scope.class === "glyphicon glyphicon-plus") //changing one class name on another 
            $scope.class = "glyphicon glyphicon-minus";
         else
            $scope.class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing the same ...

Add a class property to your objects

```
var plusClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus";
var minusClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-minus";

$scope.bands = [
    {...  ,  "genre":"aaa", "class": plusClass},
    {.... , "genre":"bbb", "class": plusClass}
];
```

Assign the band.class property to the html class attribute.
Pass the index as a parameter of the function

```
      <div ng-click="changeClass($index)" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" ng-href="#collapse{{band.index}}" >
             <img ng-src="{{band.image}}" alt="">
             <p class="output">{{band.artist}}</p>
             <p class="output">{{band.track}}</p>
             <p class="output">{{band.collection}}</p>
             <p class="output">{{band.genre}}</p>
             <span ng-class="{{band.class}}"></span> <!-- class name change-->
      </div>
```

Set it on the method

```
$scope.changeClass = function(index) {
   var actualClass = $scope.bands[index].class;
   $scope.bands[index].class = (actualClass === plusClass) ? minusClass : plusClass;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that all of your rows are binding to the same variable, which is why the icon changes for every row. Instead, you'll need to track a separate variable for each row. It looks like you already have a good candidate, `band.index`, to track which icon was chosen.

JS

```
var classes = [];
$scope.getClass = function (index) {
    // Return the current class or a reasonable default
    return classes[index] || 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus';
};
$scope.changeClass = function (index) {
    if (classes[index] === "glyphicon glyphicon-plus") //changing one class name on another 
        classes[index] = "glyphicon glyphicon-minus";
    else
        classes[index] = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus";
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-click="changeClass(band.index)" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" ng-href="#collapse{{band.index}}" > 
    <img ng-src="{{band.image}}" alt=""> 
    <p class="output">{{band.artist}}</p>
    <p class="output">{{band.track}}</p>  
    <p class="output">{{band.collection}}</p>  
    <p class="output">{{band.genre}}</p>    
    <span ng-class="getClass(band.index)"></span> <!-- class name change--> 
</div>
```